# Icons on button

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have ImageButton with Android icon:

```
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="Icon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
                />
```

How to change this icon to "confirm". I would like to use icon from standard Android library. How to do that? What logic I should go find required icon in standard Android library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio already has bunch of commonly used icons.
Steps to get the icon :

1. Right-click on `drawable` folder
2. Select new and the select vector asset
3. Click on clipart and search for the required icon
4. Choose your icon and set name and color
5. Finish

Step 1 :
[image: Step 1]

Step 2 :
[image: Step 2]

Step 3 :
[image: Step 3]

Step 4 :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are new to Android!

use [Material button](https://m2.material.io/components/buttons#anatomy) if you like to have more features.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/confirmBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Filled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_android
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconPadding="8dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/green"/>
```

Image button has only a icon without any text or label.

You can also use android `<Button` tag instead and set its `text` to "confirm".

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:text="Confirm"/>
```

Try to change `<Button` tag to `<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton` and see the result.

Comment: But how to get `confirm` icon instead of `ic_android`

Comment: On left pannel (files and class and folders) `right click` > `new` > `vector asset`, then click the icon: